# TestLink API to update execution status at test step level

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, java, testlink

I am working on a Automation Testing Framework for UI (browser) testing using selenium.

We are using Test Link for storing test cases and managing execution status.

We are using Test Link api to update the execution status back in test link after execution, but the status gets updated at test case level.

I need to update the execution status at test step level also.

Need insights into this.
Below is the code i have used.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIClient;
import testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIException;
import testlink.api.java.client.TestLinkAPIResults;

public class AutomatedUpdateExample {

    public static String DEVKEY = "2f404203b306bd8dd811a7f824c194d0";
    public static String URL = "http://localhost/testlink/lib/api/xmlrpc/v1/xmlrpc.php";

    public static void reportResult(String TestProject, String TestPlan, String Testcase, String Build, String Notes, String Result) throws TestLinkAPIException {
        TestLinkAPIClient api = new TestLinkAPIClient(DEVKEY, URL);
        api.reportTestCaseResult(TestProject, TestPlan, Testcase, Build, Notes, Result);
    }

    @Test
    public void Test1() throws Exception {
        AutomatedUpdateExample a = new AutomatedUpdateExample();
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 600);
        String testProject = "Gmail";
        String testPlan = "SampleTestPlan";
        String testCase = "GmailLogin1";
        String build = "SampleBuild";
        String notes = null;
        String result = null;
        try {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1");
            driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("testlink.msoftgp");
            driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("*******");
            driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("+Testlink")));
            result = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_PASSED;
            notes = "Executed successfully";
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            result = TestLinkAPIResults.TEST_FAILED;
            notes = "Execution failed";
        } finally {
            a.reportResult(testProject, testPlan, testCase, build, notes, result);
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```